# How can I join two Firestore queries using rxfire and rxjs (OR query)

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, rxfire

The goal is simple: to join two firestore queries utilizing `rxjs`, `rxfire`, and the `rnfirebase` react native library.

I've read multiple tutorials [1](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/performing-or-queries-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-for-javascript-with-rxjs-c361671b201e), [2](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/introduction-to-rxfire-rxjs-for-firebase/) on joining queries, but they all fail with different errors.

```js
//Simple test for collectionData
import { collectionData } from 'rxfire/firestore';

this.myQuery = this.props.docRef.collection(`messages`).where('read', 'array-contains', this.props.me.uid)
collectionData(this.myQuery, 'id').subscribe(docs => console.log(docs))
//Fails with error: this._next is not a function.
```

Alternatively,

```js
this.publicQuery = this.props.docRef.collection('messages').where('public', '==', true) 
this.myQuery = this.props.docRef.collection(`messages`).where('read', 'array-contains', this.props.me.uid)
const myQuery$ = new Rx.Subject();
const publicQuery$ = new Rx.Subject();
this.myQuery.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    myQuery$.next(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()  ));
});
this.publicQuery.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    publicQuery$.next(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()  ));
});
const orQuery$ = combineLatest(this.myQuery, this.publicQuery).switchMap((docs) => {
    var [one, two] = docs;
    var combined = one.concat(two);
    return Rx.Observable.of(combined);
})
orQuery$.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('>>>> ', result)
})
//TypeError: undefined is not a function (near ...switchMap)
```

How can I successfully join two firestore queries (OR)?

Comment: What version of RxJS are you using? Are you using rxjs-compat ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're already very close to the solution. Let's go through the issues step-by-step.

First, it's not necessary to create a `Subject` just to transform your result from `onSnapshot`. Instead of this:

```
this.myQuery.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    myQuery$.next(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
});
```

We can achieve the same using 'pipeable transformation operators':

```
const myQuery$ = this.myQuery.onSnapshot.pipe(
    map(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
);
```

The same goes for the other query:

```
const publicQuery$ = this.publicQuery.onSnapshot.pipe(
    map(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data())
);
```

Second, to join those two queries, `combineLatest` is indeed the correct creation function.

However, your error might result from you using a newer RxJS version, that doesn't support 'fluent' operators ([officially called "patch operators"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)) anymore. They have been replaced by 'pipeable operators' from RxJS 6 onwards. As an example, `myObs$.map(...)` has become `myObs$.pipe(map(...))`. The tutorials probably use an older version of RxJS where the first is still possible.

Also, it shouldn't be necessary to use `switchMap` if the inner Observable is just an `of` operator. It is sufficient in this case to use the `map` operator, which will behave equally.

Using the new RxJS 6+ syntax together with `map`, the combination will look like this:

```
const orQuery$ = combineLatest(myQuery$, publicQuery$).pipe(
    map(([one, two]) => one.concat(two))
)
```

The rest of your code should be correct.

**Side Note:** Keep in mind that the equivalent of your code in SQL is `UNION` (not `JOIN`). In order to `JOIN` programatically, you'd need to combine each object of result set A with each object of result set B and create a joined object for each pair. Such a function for a keyless `OUTER JOIN` would look like this (placed in your `map` pipe):

```
one.map(a => 
   two.map(b => Object.assign({}, a, b)))
.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), [])
```

If you want to have a `UNION` with no duplicate objects, concat only those items from `two` that have no matching primary key in list `one`. This would be your mapping function:

```
one.concat(two.filter(twoItem => !one.some(oneItem => oneItem.id == twoItem.id)))
```

**DEMO:** A complete, working demo with the above code and a simulated FireStore can be found here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mefynu?devtoolsheight=60