# Inner join collections based on locations with geofireX

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, geofire

I want to fetch and join multiple collections based on user's location with geofirex:

Here's my code when I get users docs based on location :
PS (This code returns only user's docs based on location)

```
getAround() {
    const center = geo.point(this.lat, this.lng);
    const field = 'location';
    this.points = this.radius.pipe(
      switchMap(r => {
        return this.geo.query(locations).within(center, r, field, { log: true });
      })
    );
}
```

How I inner join collections with Rxjs :

```
 getAll() {
      const allPosts = this.afStore.collection<Service>('services')
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          switchMap(services => {
            const res = services.map((service: Service) => {
              return this.afStore.doc<UserModel>(`users/${service.userId}`)
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(
                map(user => Object.assign(service, { user }))
              );
            });
            return combineLatest([...res]); })
        )
         .pipe(
          switchMap(servuser => {
            const ress = servuser.map((service: Service) => {
              return this.afStore.doc<Category>(`categorys/${service.iconId}`)
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(
                map(category => Object.assign(service, { category }))
              );
            });
            return combineLatest([... ress]);
          })
        );
      return allPosts;
    }
```

The problem is I can't mix these codes together so I can get my data joined and based on user's location,

I get this [error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZAt2.png)

```
(alias) interface Service 
import Service 
Argument of type '(service: Service) => Observable<Service & { user: UserModel; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: GeoQueryDocument, index: number, array: GeoQueryOocument[]) => Observable<Service & { user: UserModel; }>'. Types of parameters 'service' and 'value' are incompatible. 

Type 'GeoQuerpocument' is missing the following properties from type 'Service': id, cost, dateCreated, discount, and 6 more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this fixed it and now my code works!

```
.pipe(
          switchMap(services => {
            const res = services.map((fromservices) => {
              return this.afStore.doc<UserModel>(`users/${fromservices['userId']}`)
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(
                map(user => Object.assign(fromservices, { user }))
              );
            });
            return combineLatest([...res]); })
        )
```

And just having this warning which is okay I guess? :

```
object access via string literals is disallowed (no-string-literal)tslint(1)
```

Comment: take a look into [this github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1923) : ` It discourages you of doing foo['bar']. As any other rule, they are optional and there are people who likes it on or off.`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `services` is from the value-index-array type, while you implicetely expect a Services array.

```
    .pipe(
      switchMap(services => { // <-- expects a Service array (but appreantly it's not)
        const res = services.map((service: Service) => { // <-- because of this
          return this.afStore.doc<UserModel>(`users/${service.userId}`)
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(user => Object.assign(service, { user }))
          );
        });
        return combineLatest([...res]); })
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any suggestions on how I can join other collections to that geo query? I've tried a lot of things but no success till now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329908/how-can-i-join-two-firestore-queries-using-rxfire-and-rxjs-or-query). They explain step by step a similar scenario to yours.

They also shared a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mefynu?devtoolsheight=60): A complete, working demo with the above code and a simulated FireStore.

Additionally to that, I found this about [Join Collections in Firestore](https://fireship.io/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/) that might be of your interest.

I suggest to take a look into the question aforementinoed. Anyway, I will add here some remarkable things of that:

> - You can use `pipeable transformation operators`:

```
const myQuery$ = this.myQuery.onSnapshot.pipe(
    map(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
);
```

> - To join those two queries, `combineLatest` is the correct creation function.

> However, your error might result from you using a newer RxJS version, that doesn't support `fluent` operators (officially called "patch operators") anymore. They have been replaced by `pipeable operators` from RxJS 6 onwards. As an example, `myObs$.map(...)` has become `myObs$.pipe(map(...))`. The tutorials probably use an older version of RxJS where the first is still possible.

> Also, it shouldn't be necessary to use `switchMap` if the inner Observable is just an of operator. It is sufficient in this case to use the `map` operator, which will behave equally.

> Using the new RxJS 6+ syntax together with map, the combination will look like this:

```
const orQuery$ = combineLatest(myQuery$, publicQuery$).pipe(
    map(([one, two]) => one.concat(two))
)
```

> Side Note: Keep in mind that the equivalent of your code in SQL is UNION (not JOIN). In order to JOIN programatically, you'd need to combine each object of result set A with each object of result set B and create a joined object for each pair. Such a function for a keyless OUTER JOIN would look like this (placed in your map pipe):

```
one.map(a => 
   two.map(b => Object.assign({}, a, b)))
.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), [])
```

> If you want to have a UNION with no duplicate objects, concat only those items from two that have no matching primary key in list one. This would be your mapping function:

```
one.concat(two.filter(twoItem => !one.some(oneItem => oneItem.id == twoItem.id)))
```